# Extern constant - Property not found on object of type

Tags: ios

I try to declare constant to be publicly accessible.

SortType.h

```
extern NSInteger const ASCENDING;
extern NSInteger const DESCENDING;
```

SortType.m

```
NSInteger const ASCENDING = 100;
NSInteger const DESCENDING = 101;
```

ViewController

```
#import "SortType.h"
...
SortType.ASCENDING;
```

But it has following error:

> Property 'ASCENDING' not found on object of type 'SortType'

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ASCENDING` is not a property of `SortType` class, it's a extern constant. So you can't use like:

```
SortType.ASCENDING;
```

Just use:

```
NSInteger myInteger = ASCENDING;
```

Comment: I see. Btw, is it possible to access a constant variable from view controller without need to create the object, just like `SortType.ASCENDING` ?

Comment: @Rendy Define an enum (For integers)